# Slow nginx behavior when using as reverse proxy for https

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, reverse-proxy

**Setup:**

1. Dummy SSL endpoint https://hookb.in/VGQ3wdGGzKSE22bwzRdP
2. Install Nginx on localhost

**Steps:**

1. Hit the `hookb.in` endpoint using browser for very first time and we get network activity like below.  It took 865 ms
   [image]
   Fig 1
2. Subsequent hit to `hookb.in` endpoint using browser take much less time as it is using the same tcp connection, below is the screen shot for ref. (All Good!!)
   [image]
   Fig 2
3. setup the http-> https reverse proxy using below nginx config

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
keepalive_timeout 65;
    server {
        listen      80;
        server_name  localhost;     
        location /session {
            proxy_pass  https://hookb.in/VGQ3wdGGzKSE22bwzRdP;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "keep-alive";
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
            proxy_socket_keepalive on;  
        }
    }
}
```

4. Now from browser hit `http://127.0.0.1/session` and nginx will work fine and proxy the content from https site.
   But nginx response time is always 200ms more than compared to accessing https site directly. Screen shot below for ref
   **Why nignx is taking extra time , is it opening new ssl connection every time or is there  something else?**
   I understand with reverse proxy we are adding extra hop , but 200ms is big difference.
   **How can i fix it ?**
   [image]

Comment: My guess is that nginx takes this time to resolve the name `hookb.in`. Put the mapping `165.227.143.146  hookb.in` to your `/etc/hosts` and check the performance.

Comment: @PakUula no thats not the issue... still 200 ms diff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration you are using implies that nginx will open a new
connection to upstream server for each proxied request.  To
configure nginx to keep upstream connections alive, please see the
description of the "keepalive" directive here:

http://nginx.org/r/keepalive

Notably, make sure to configure an upstream block with the
"keepalive" directive.  Something like this at the http level
should work, assuming no other changes in the configuration:

```
upstream hookb.in {
    server hookb.in:443;
    keepalive 2;
}
```

In the example above, nginx will keep up to two connections.

(This is mostly unchanged copy of my [response](http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2020-September/059932.html) in the nginx mailing list.)

Comment: can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74498407/nginx-windows-load-balancing-very-slow-for-single-request , I have been facing related issue